# Regular expression is not working in Android 5.0 +

Tags: android, jquery, regex, cordova, keyup

```
$(document).on("keyup", ".rate", function (e) {
    var val = this.value;
    var re1 = /^([0-9]{1,7}(?:\.[0-9]{0,3})?)/g;
    val = re1.exec(val);
    if (val) {
      this.value = val[0];
    } else {
      this.value = "";
    }
});
```

Above regular expression I am using in one of my app which is working fine below Android 5.0 but above android 5 it is not working.

Please help me out what mistake is been done. App is been created using JQuery, Cordova 3.2+

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var re1 = /^([0-9]{1,7}(?:\.[0-9]{0,3})?)/g
```

Remove ;